# Is it possible to declare Ext.Component as global variables?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I've faced with this problem many times when optimize my Sencha Touch 2 apps.

It's obvious that I should keep the DOM light-weighted, my application contains an `Ext.TabBar` and a main `Ext.Container` above. Everytime when switch from a view to another, I simply remove current view and add new view to that Container.

But the problem is, there are some views which have **customized data**. I mean they have inner data such as html content, filtered store records, etc. When I remove them from my main Container, I want to somehow save their "states" to a global variable, for example: I'm doing an e-Commerce app with products with details. When remove details panel from main container, I want to do something like this:

```
var saved_detail_panel = mainContainer.getActiveItem();
```

if I could do that, later when I want to add that detail panel back to main container, I can simply use:

```
mainContainer.add(saved_detail_panel);
```

I've tried many times but could not find one that works yet.

Highly appreciate for any helps. Thank you.

**Updated**:
When I put this code in my event handler in a controller:

```
var temp = Ext.create('taxi.view.location.LocationPanel', {showAnimation: null});
taxi.main_container = temp;
```

It works well but is not performant. The thing I want to do is to create it once only in my **app.js**, like this:

```
launch: function(){
var temp = Ext.create('taxi.view.location.LocationPanel', {showAnimation: null});
};
```

and only use this in Controller:

```
taxi.main_container = temp;
```

It works for the first time. But in the second time, it shows this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replaceCls' of null
```

Comment: Wonder if it's a ST2 bug like this one: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?189025-Calling-Ext.Msg.show-with-items-second-time-gives-an-error  ... I see about 20 invocations of replaceCls in sencha-touch-all-debug.js  Can you see which one is being called from the Chrome stacktrace?

Comment: my bad, I'm not patient enough to backtrace and debug those core sources :( ... even when I've found a work-around now, by using kind of this: `mainContainer.add({xtype: 'LocationPanel', showAnimation: null});` it still shows a weird error in Chrome dev tools: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the app's "global namespace"?  Then you can reference MyApp.savedValue anywhere in your app?

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

//    views: [],
//    models: [],
//    stores: [],
    controllers: ['Main'],

    launch: function() {
        MyApp.savedValue = "Hello word";
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Sencha.view.tablet.MainView'));
    }
});
```

One other idea in the Sencha examples is in the KitchenSink demo.  In [app/controllers/Main.js](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/app/controller/Main.js), they use a view cache, which is setup in the config:{} and accessed via a getter/setter.  I think the main controller always persists so your cache is always available.  In fact, aren't all of your controllers persist if they're loaded in the app.js?

```
 controllers: ['Main','FooController', 'BarController'],
```

Snippets from: [app/controllers/Main.js](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/app/controller/Main.js)

```
config: {
        /**
         * @private
         */
        viewCache: [], // Accessed via getViewCache(), setViewCache()

        ...
},

 createView: function(name) {
        var cache = this.getViewCache(), // Implied getter
            ln = cache.length,
            limit = 20, // max views to cache
            view, i, oldView;

       // See if view is already in the cache and return it
        Ext.each(cache, function(item) {
            if (item.viewName === name) {
                view = item;
                return;
            }
        }, this);

        if (view) {
            return view;
        }

        // If we've reached our cache limit then remove something

        if (ln >= limit) {
            for (i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
                oldView = cache[i];
                if (!oldView.isPainted()) {
                    oldView.destroy();
                    cache.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // Create the view and add it to the cache
        view = Ext.create(name);
        view.viewName = name;
        cache.push(view);
        this.setViewCache(cache); // Implied setter

        return view;
    },
```

Comment: I've tried many times but unfortunately, global namespace does not work. It always causes errors and cannot be updated directly. By the way, can you explain more about `viewCache`?

Comment: I've tried to expand on what I know so far.  I'll need to figure this out too at some point.  I think you're a little farther ahead in your development.

Comment: please see my updated question, that's truly the problem I've faced so many times before and got so frustrated ..

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var appNS = new Ext.application({

    name: 'app',
    //others

    launch: function () {    
        appNS.SavedValue = 'getting start..........';       
    },

    //others

});
```

and then you can use it inside of controller

```
console.log(appNs.SavedValue);
```

i hope it might be helpful.

Comment: unfortunately, that's local variable, not global one

Answer (score 0):

another soln is caching ur views. it is not actually caching.
first add an array to your application like .

```
Ext.application({
name: 'app',


viewCache: [],

viewCacheCount: 0,


launch: function () {     

    this.viewCache.push("app init......."); // push your view

}
});
```

and this can be retrive inside of any controller something like

```
ths.getApplication().viewCache.pop();      //pop your view
```

I dont know it might create some problem in case of some views/components that are auto destroyable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `autoDestroy: false` in your view.

```
Ext.define('JiaoJiao.view.personal.Card', {

 extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
 xtype: 'personalContainer',

 config: {

     tab: {
         title: '个人',
         iconCls: 'user',
         action: 'personalTab'
     },

     autoDestroy: false,

     items: [
         {
             xtype:'personal',
             store: 'Personals'
         }
     ]
 }
});
```